# Object Moved error html to php

Tags: php, html, user-input, xml

I honestly don't know what's wrong. Every time I try to add an account to my xml database file, it doesn't get written in the file. I don't see anything wrong with my code.

When I click my submit button this page's content is displayed

#### Object Moved

### This document may be found *here*

//This is me testing my code below

hey im in the if statement 
hogwartsBoss 
swag 
hogwartsBoss@gmail.com 
Harry 
Potter 
BabyMetal Head Bangya!! 
Iron Madien Run to the Hills 
japybunnyhijapygen@yahoo.com genesis Bejarano

#### HTML SIGN UP FILE

```
 <!--This is the sign up section on the Home Website page -->    
<form method="post" action="sign_up.php">
First Name:<input type= "text" name="first"/><br /><br />
Last Name:<input type= "text" name="last"/><br /><br />
Email:<input type= "text" name="email"/><br /><br />
Username:<input type= "text" name="username"/><br /><br />
Password:<input type= "password" name="password"/><br /><br />
<input type= "submit"  name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
</form>
```

#### PHP SIGN UP FILE

```
$f = $l = $e= $user = $pass = null;
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {
echo "hey im in the if statement";
include 'xmlconnect.php';
$f=vaildName($_POST['first']);
$l=vaildName($_POST['last']);
$e=vaildEmail($_POST['email']);
$user= $_POST['username'];
$pass= $_POST['password'];

$credTag = $xml->addChild('credentials');
//user account info
$userTag = $credTag->addChild('username',$user);
$passTag = $credTag->addChild('password',$pass);
$emailTag = $credTag->addChild('email',$e);
$infoTag = $credTag->addChild('info');
$firstTag = $infoTag->addChild('first',$f);
$lastTag = $infoTag->addChild('last',$l);

 file_put_contents('UserAccountDB.xml',$xml->asXML());

    echo $xml->asXML();
//  echo "updated database";

//  printf($xml);

//redirects you to the homepage
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = $user;
//$url = "http://cs3360.cs.utep.edu/gbejarano/WebStore/UserAccountDB.xml";
//$url = "http://cs3360.cs.utep.edu/gbejarano/WebStore/myLibrary.php";
//$url = 'http://localhost/Music_Webstore/myLibrary.php';
header('Location: '.$url);
}
```

Comment: Please post your errors

Comment: you may need to specify the full path to your object in the file, as it is not being found

Comment: I thought I was doing that with the action part of the form?

Comment: not the php call, the actual object in the xml

Comment: try specifying the full path to UserAccountDB.xml.  Also try xmlconnect.php Other than that, I'm not sure

Comment: pls show a working minimum of your code, e.g. xmlconnect.php and a valid minimum snippet of your xml.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great misunderstanding here:

> Object Moved
>
> This document may be found here

is ***not*** an error message. It's your web-server's standard response body of a message in the Redirect 3xx group. Those do not denote errors, just standard redirects.

Those redirects are expected because you answer with a redirect:

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

However using

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

before the header command does not work at all. Please consult the PHP manual on how to do a proper redirect and related to other existing Q&A material here on site as well ***before*** you draw wild assumptions in a new question and label non-errors as errors and cause other confusion.

If certain words are not clear to you, ask about the words first.

If you have problem to decipher a message the computer gives to you, ask about the message first.

Do not post live code. Instead create a new example from scratch that contains as little code and data as necessary to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I believe the OP lacks enough understanding to create a new example.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the solution is simple:

It wasn't my code it was my school server security

Comment: @JanTuroň Actually this IS the solution;-)

Comment: ... and pretty useless to everyone. I'd describe what the "school server security" means at least (like hakre in the other answer). SO answers are not just about mere SOLUTION, but about EXPLANATION, I believe.